# REGEXP Substring Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm looking for a regexp to get the correct file name from the below string.

Input

```
Report_18072014.pdf
```

Expected Output

```
Report.pdf
```

The query so far which gives me the correct output.

```
REPLACE(FILENAME, '_' || TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (FILENAME, '[^_.]+',1,2)))
```

My question is if there is a better regexp I can use to avoid concatenating `_` to the substring in the `replace` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your file format, you can use something like this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(FILENAME, '^([[:alnum:]]+)_[^.]+(\.[^.]+)',
                         '\1\2',
                         1, 0, 'c')
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `([[:alnum:]]+)` captures letters to Group 1.
- `[^.]+` matches any chars that are not a `.`
- `(\.[^.]+)` captures the extension to Group 2 (the dot and any chars that are not a dot)
- `\1\2` replaces with Group 1, Group 2

Comment: FYI: added explanation for the regex. :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81. This one worked as expected for me. `REGEXP_REPLACE(FILENAME,'_[[:alnum:]]+')`  +1 for the explanation though.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the answer.

Comment: Thanks. FYI if you know it's only digits after the underscore, you can use `[[:digit:]]+` instead of `[[:alnum:]]+` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this [untested]:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(FILENAME, '_[[:digit:]]*\.', '.')
```

I really enjoy using regular expressions, but I wish that Oracle used the PCRE format instead of the POSIX format.

Explanation:

- _[[:digit:]]* matches the underscore and 0 or more digits.
- . matches the period to make sure that you are beside the file extension
- The final , '.' replaces everything with a period so that you have still have the .PDF

I would have changed the replacement to '.PDF', but I don't want to force your file names to mixed case files.

Comment: Thanks. This worked as well. But accepting @zx81 solution for it being more generic of replacing string between 2 characters.