# How to find a string inside a string and print it?

Tags: string, oracle

How to print a string inside a string?
I have row data like this

**City_name**
Abcde/def/Report_names/**names**

Now i want to print only that string which is after report_names

1. Abcde/def length may vary from line to line.
2. Report_names/names is standard naming format.
3. So i want to print only text appearing after /report_names/

Comment: please show what have you tried before you ask a question. I am sure we have plenty of examples. `select regexp_substr('City_name Abcde/def/Report_names/naxsusmes', 'Report_names/(.+)$', 1, 1, null, 1) from dual`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REGEXP Substring Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877519/regexp-substring-oracle)

Comment: @saikumarm - for problems like this, it is best to look for similar questions where the answers use standard string functions, not regular expressions. You don't need a cannon to kill a fly.

Answer (score 1):

For simple exercises like this, it is best to **learn** and then use standard string functions, `INSTR` and `SUBSTR`. `instr` will find the position of the first letter of a substring you are searching for within a longer string. So if you search for `'Report_names/'` you will find the position of `R`. The first letter of "names" is 13 positions to the right of that. That will be the first letter of the substring you **actually** want, which is the "names". With this you should be able to understand what the query below does:

```
-- begin TEST DATA (not part of the solution to the problem)
with
     test_data ( str ) as (
       select 'City_name Abcde/def/Report_names/Ann, Helen, Mary' from dual
     )
-- end of TEST DATA; SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE 
-- use your actual table and column names instead of "test_data" and "str"
select str, substr( str, instr(str, 'Report_names/') + 13 ) as names
from   test_data
;

STR                                                 NAMES
-------------------------------------------------   --------------------
City_name Abcde/def/Report_names/Ann, Helen, Mary   Ann, Helen, Mary

1 row selected.
```